Show directory owner id instead of name via FTP (Filezilla)
I am setting up the directory permission of a fresh new linux Debian 12 server.
I have added my user(uid=1000) to the www-data group.
My commands are as below -
sudo chown -R 1000:www-data public_html/
sudo chmod -R g+s public_html/

But when I go to filezilla I see
user www-data and not 1000 www-data
Is there anyway I can show the ID and not name.
Thanks in advance.

You've added a user account with uid=1000, so the system will use that account name whenever and wherever possible
